# Myspace Developers Portal no Access

Tags: api, myspace, email-verification

I want to create a new application at myspace but when I tried to get access to myspace API.
I always get the following message:

> We're sorry, but you must verify your email address first! You cannot access many MySpace features until you complete this step. Please return to your MySpace profile and click the "Verify your email address" link. When this step is complete, you can re-apply to the developer platform. I have verify my email – so I don’t know what to do to get access.

I clicked on the link in the email I get after the registration. But I didn't find another link - and I still get the same message.